# Splitting field of polynomial with radical roots $f(X)= X^4-6X^2-2$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, radicals, splitting-field

I am trying to find $Gal(L:\mathbb Q)$ where $L$ is the splitting field of $f(X)= X^4-6X^2-2$ over $\mathbb Q$.

My working so far:

I have worked out that the four roots are $\pm \sqrt{3+\sqrt{11}} $ and $\pm i\sqrt{-3+\sqrt{11}}$. And I'm quite stuck on how to find the splitting field, intuition tells me that it could be $\mathbb Q((\sqrt{3+\sqrt{11}}),i)$, let $\alpha=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{11}} $ so $\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q$ but I have doubts and the radicals have really confused me.

$\alpha=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{11}}$ and $\beta = \pm i\sqrt{-3+\sqrt{11}}$

What I think are the automorphisms:

id: $\alpha \mapsto \alpha, \beta \mapsto \beta$

$\theta_1: \alpha \mapsto \alpha, \beta \mapsto -\beta$

$\theta_2: \alpha \mapsto \beta, \beta \mapsto \alpha$

$\theta_3 : \alpha \mapsto -\beta, \beta \mapsto -\alpha$

$\theta_3\theta_2: \alpha \mapsto -\alpha, \beta \mapsto \beta$

$\theta_3^2: \alpha \mapsto -\alpha, \beta \mapsto -\beta$

$\theta_1\theta_2: \alpha \mapsto -\beta, \beta \mapsto \alpha$

$\theta_3^2\theta_2: \alpha \mapsto -\beta, \beta \mapsto -\alpha$

I'm very stumped, can anyone help?

Comment: Last time I checked $\Bbb{Q}$ already has infinitely many elements. Therefore the tag [tag:finite-fields] was misplaced :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen oops, my mistake! :P Could you explain why the splitting field is $\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta)$ and advise me how to write out my automorphisms of the galois group?

Comment: Anyway, your intuition is slightly miscalibrated. You can verify easily that $\alpha\beta=i\sqrt2$ (or $-i\sqrt2$, depending on which of those number you really called $\beta$). Because $f(x)$ is irreducible, the extension $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)/\Bbb{Q}$ has degree four. When you further adjoin $i\sqrt2$ you get the splitting field. After all, $\beta=i\sqrt2/\alpha\in\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,i\sqrt2)$.

Comment: May be your intuition was based on examples such as splitting fields of $x^4-7$, where you get the other zeros by multiplying one of them with powers of $i$? In that case you do get the splitting field by adjoining $i$ and one of the roots. Here that no longer works.

Comment: Yes that's exactly where my intuition came from. For my automorphisms, I want to try and write them out in the form of a the dihederal group $D_8$, would making $\delta$ the one that sends $i$ to $-i$ and $\theta$ the one that sends $\alpha$ to $i\alpha$ work? Sorry for all my questions, thanks for you help!

Comment: Anyway, an automoprhism of a splitting field is always uniquely determined when you know how it maps the roots of $f(x)$., i.e. the numbers $\pm\alpha,\pm\beta$. An automorphism can map $\alpha$ to any of the four roots. But then you also know where $-\alpha$ goes, so that leaves two alternatives for the image of $\beta$. This way you get the required 8 automorphisms.

Comment: Forget about $i$, it is not an element of this splitting field. It's getting late here. If no one else bites I will type a detailed answer in the morning (or look for a closely related example - this feels vaguely familiar).

Comment: Thank you again, I've corrected my automorphisms, are they right? Is there a neater way to write them in notation out in their Galois group? Somehow I don't think $\{ id, \theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_3\theta_2,\theta_3^2,\theta_1\theta_2,\theta_3^2\theta_2 \}$ is the best way to write it haha

Comment: $\theta_1$ is complex conjugation, so that is an automorphism. As $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$ are conjugate over $\Bbb Q$ there is an automorphism taking $\alpha$ to $\pm\beta$, so one of $\theta_2$, $\theta_3$, $\theta_1\theta_2$ and $\theta_3^2\theta_2$ is an automorphism. Call this automorphism $\sigma$. But then these four automorphisms listed above are $\sigma$, $\theta_1\sigma$, $\sigma\theta_1$, $\theta_1\sigma\theta_1$ so all of these are genuine automorphisms. It follows easily then that all the maps you have are automorphisms. They form a dihedral group.

Comment: Did you intend $\theta_3$ to map $\alpha\mapsto\beta, \beta\mapsto -\alpha$?

Answer (score 2):

The splitting field is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{11}},i\sqrt{-3+\sqrt{11}})$.
Complex conjugation induces an automorphism of $L$ fixing $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{11}}$
and sending $i\sqrt{-3+\sqrt{11}}$ to its negative. This should help
explicate the action of the Galois group on the four zeros of $f$.